# Objective C/Swift conversion: How to do this in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert this example here:
https://github.com/NilStack/NKWatchChart

to swift2-code. I'm having problems with exactly this part:

```
data01.getData = ^(NSUInteger index) {
        CGFloat yValue = [data01Array[index] floatValue];
        return [NKLineChartDataItem dataItemWithY:yValue];
};
```

getData is defined as follows:

```
public class NKLineChartData : NSObject {

  public var color: UIColor!
  public var alpha: CGFloat
  public var itemCount: UInt
  public var getData: LCLineChartDataGetter!
```

The LCLineChartDataGetter is a type alias:

```
public typealias LCLineChartDataGetter = (UInt) -> NKLineChartDataItem!
```

I'm pretty new to objective-c and swift, so maybe someone can point me to how the assignment can be done using swift!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing being assigned to `getData` in Obj-C is a block that takes an integer parameter and returns a `NKLineChartDataItem`. (Check something like http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com if you need help remembering these.)

In Swift, the formal syntax for the corresponding [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID95) looks like this:

```
data01.getData = { (index: UInt) -> NKLineChartDataItem! in
   // body
}
```

But you can also use type inference to shorten it:

```
data01.getData = { index in
   // body
}
```

Looking at more of the example from the NKWatchChart readme you linked to:

```
NSArray * data01Array = @[@60.1, @160.1, @126.4, @0.0, @186.2, @127.2, @176.2];
NKLineChartData *data01 = [NKLineChartData new];
data01.color = NKGreen;
data01.alpha = 0.9f;
data01.itemCount = data01Array.count;
data01.inflexionPointStyle = NKLineChartPointStyleTriangle;
data01.getData = ^(NSUInteger index) {
    CGFloat yValue = [data01Array[index] floatValue];
    return [NKLineChartDataItem dataItemWithY:yValue];
};
```

You can probably shorten this even more through native Swift types:

```
let data01Array: [CGFloat] = [60.1, 160.1, 126.4, 0.0, 186.2, 127.2, 176.2]
let data01 = NKLineChartData()
data01.color = NKGreen
data01.alpha = 0.9
data01.itemCount = data01Array.count
data01.inflexionPointStyle = .Triangle;
data01.getData = { NKLineChartDataItem(y: data01Array[$0]) }
```

Comment: (Note the example at the end is untested.)

Comment: Not working for Swift 2.2.  Error:
cannot assign value of type '(UInt) -> NKLineChartDataItem' to type 'NKLineChartDataItem!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution myself. The equivalent in Swift is:

```
    data01.getData = {(index : UInt) -> NKLineChartDataItem in
        let yValue : CGFloat = CGFloat(data01Array[Int(index)] as! NSNumber)
        return NKLineChartDataItem.init(y: yValue)
    }
```

Maybe someone has a better/shorter solution but the above seems to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert swift to objective-c to make it run in your project. Just drag the swift into your project and Xcode will automatically generate a bridging header for you

Comment: I would like to convert the objective-c code to swift since i don't like objective-c ;) . I already have a running swift project and would like to use the chart tool. So i have to convert the example to swift ;) .